# SQL Server - same table for multiple customers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a need to manage a dataset for multiple customers - each customer manages a small table to update procedure volumes for the next five years. The table is structured like so:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|             | Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3 | Year 4 | Year 5 |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Procedure A | 5      | 10     | 14     | 12     | 21     |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Procedure B | 23     | 23     | 2      | 3      | 4      |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Procedure C | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 12     |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The values in this table will be managed by each customer via MS PowerApps.

This same structure exists for every single customer. What is the best way to put all of these in one dataset?

Should I just add a column for `CUSTOMER ID` and just put all the data in there?

The process:

1. Utilizing PowerApps, a new customer deal will be generated and a row will be added for them in the SQL DB in a customer records table.
2. Simultaneously, the blank template of the above table should be generated for them.
3. Now, the customer can interface with this SQL table within PowerApps and add their respective procedure volumes.

Comment: (1) Add a `CustomerId` column to `Customers` and manage all of the implications of multiple customers playing in the same pool. (B) Use a separate database for each customer with all of the needed tables &c. and keep them completely independent. As it stands your question is not really about programming and far too vague to answer, e.g. is a "customer" someone ordering comfy pillows or independent healthcare systems for which you manage patient data?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Is it possible to use views in PowerApps instead. You can have a single table with CustomerId column but in view, a `WHERE` clause can be added to filter CustomerId = 9. Single physical table but separate view for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't explained well but:

I would assume all of the customer specific data has at least one column that is the same.  For instance CustomerName.  You could create your own table with CustomerId, CustomerName, (any other fields you would like to see).  If there isn't a concept of CustomerId on the customer's tables, you would have to join them on CustomerName.  You could populate your own CustomerId for the new table.

I would be happy to help more if you could clarify the question and show a few examples.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: So you're saying the table you provided is a sql table per customer and you have many of these tables in the database?

Comment: Each time a customer cuts a deal, we would need to generate a blank template of this table for them to enter values.

Comment: But once they enter the values, where does the data get stored?

Comment: I added in some more data to the question. The goal is to have a massive table - made up of each customer table. We would be generating a blank version of the above table once the customer cuts a deal. I am thinking we just append it to the existing megastructure.

Comment: Yes if you have the ability to write the customer data into your table, I would just add a customerid field as a FK that would connect to your internal customers table.